# What is the idiomatic way in Scala to pattern match on a type hierarchy with TypeTag?

Tags: scala, reflection, pattern-matching, scala-2.10

I have a type hierarchy and want to ask a lookup method for an implementation. I am having trouble doing this without resorting to an `asInstanceOf` call.

So giving a simple type hierarchy like so

```
trait Vehicle

trait Flying extends Vehicle
class Plane extends Flying

trait Driving extends Vehicle
class Car extends Driving

trait Swimming extends Vehicle
class Boat extends Swimming
```

my lookup method is like this

```
def findVehicle[V <: Vehicle](implicit tag: TypeTag[V]): Option[V] = {

  val v = tag.tpe match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Flying] => Some(new Plane)
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Driving] => Some(new Car)
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Swimming] => Some(new Boat)
    case _ => None
  }

  v.map(_.asInstanceOf[V])
}
```

with a lookup like so

```
println(findVehicle[Flying])  // Some(Plane@5b7fd935)
```

Is it possible to achieve a lookup like this without the `asInstanceOf` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using `TypeTag` and use a type class instead.

```
trait Builder[+T] {
  def build: Option[T]
}

implicit val flyingBuilder = new Builder[Flying] {
  def build = Some(new Plane)
}

implicit val drivingBuilder = new Builder[Driving] {
  def build = Some(new Car)
}

implicit val swimmingBuilder = new Builder[Swimming] {
  def build = Some(new Boat)
}

implicit val anyBuilder = new Builder[Nothing] {
  def build = None
}

def findVehicle[V <: Vehicle](implicit b: Builder[V]): Option[V] = b.build
```

No reflection involved and it's definitely more idiomatic.

Note how defining a `Builder[Nothing]` reproduces the same behavior you achieved by returning a `None`. This is not necessarily a good idea, as you're now forced to check whether the method was able to produce a value or not.

I would rather prefer a compile-time error if it's impossible to build the instance of the desired type, and you achieve it by directly returning `T` as opposed to `Option[T]` from `build` (and of course getting rid of the `Nothing` case).

Comment: This looks promising, but how does one handle the `case _ => None` scenario?

Comment: To make the above comment more clear: if `flyingBuilder` is not defined, we get a compile error, instead of a `None` result from `findVehicle`

Comment: I updated my answer. Since `Builder` is covariant you can simply have `build` to return an `Option[T]` and have a `Builder[Nothing]` in scope.

Comment: The above actually did not work: `findVehicle[Flying]` resulted in an `ambiguous implicit values` compiler error and `findVehicle[Plane]` used the `anyBuilder` implicit resulting in `None`